# Scala Repll - How to create import packages?

Tags: scala

Replit URL: https://replit.com/@spidey1405/Scala-Practice#main.scala

I am using Scala Replit to practice some Scala Practice problems. My file structure is like this:

```
./
- main.scala
- TwoSum.scala
```

My `TwoSum.scala` file looks like this:

```
object TwoSum {

  def sumExists(item:Int, rest:Array[Int], target: Int) {
    if(rest.length == 0) return -1
    val current = rest.head
    if(item + current == target) return current
    return sumExists(item, rest.tail, target)
  }
  def findTwoSum(array:Array[Int], target: Int) {
    if(array.length < 2) return Array(-1,-1)
    val current = array.head
    val rest = array.tail
    val complement = sumExist(current, rest, target)
    if(complement != -1) return Array(current, complement)
    if(rest.length < 2) return Array(-1,-1)
    return findTwoSum(rest.tail, target)
    
  }
}
```

Now I need to import this object to be consumed in main.scala but not able to understand how can I do so:

```
import com.TwoSum.TwoSum

import TwoSum.TwoSum
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val twoSum = TwoSum.findTwoSum(Array(2,4,8,14),22)
    println("Two Sum = ", twoSum.mkstring(","))
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually you define a `package` at the top of the file to define in which package the object/class should live. And then you can import from this package. If you don't specify a package, your `TwoSum` lives in the root package `_root_`.

Comment: So you mean I need to do `import _root_.TwoSum`?

Comment: No, these files should see each other's top-level definitions without any imports as they are in the same package.